# Jenkins / Maven Release Plugin SVN - Credentials

Tags: jenkins, svn, credentials, maven-release-plugin

I have **Jenkins Version 2.89.4**  with the actual **MavenReleasePlugin** and **SVN** as repository. The SVN - Credentials set in the project configuration will not be used from the MavenReleasePlugin as I am aware.

Do I press in  Jenkins the Build Release Button, I may enter user and password for SVN. This works fine, but it is work interactive.

How and where can I store these credentials in the background in Jenkins  or any settings.xml ? so that I don't have to enter the credentials each time I am building a release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell maven NOT to work in interactive mode using

```
mvn -B release:prepare
```

or

```
mvn --batch-mode release:prepare
```

Using batch mode with no other configuration will cause the Release Plugin to use **default values** for the release version, the SCM tag, and the next development version. These values can also be set from the **command line**. So you can set in the command line the "-username" and "-password" arguments.

Another option is to create a **properties file** that contains the version information for the project you would like to release. In this property file you can place the username and password.

Read more [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html) and [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wonder why the plugin does not use the credentials for SVN configured in the Jenkins-Job. That is what I would expect...